# Why doesn't IE/Chrome on Windows support SOCKS5 proxies on port 27977?

Tags: windows, google-chrome, proxy, socks

I am working with a client who uses proxies on their Windows machines. They recently have come to me to solve the issue of why Interenet Explorer and Chrome refuse to use SOCKS5 proxies on port 27977. I believe it has something to do with the fact that all the proxies on 27977 are implemented in pure SOCKS5. I can get Firefox to work just fine with these proxies in Windows, as well as Chrome under Ubuntu. Sidenote: my Nexus One will work with them too on Firefox for Android. I am wondering if their is a patch, or if IE9 would have better support etc. Thanks for any help guys.

Answer (score 3):

IE9 will work fine with a SOCKS5 proxy (it detects the type of proxy automatically).

For Chrome however, you can use the [command line](http://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/) to force Chrome to use a SOCKS5 proxy rather than trying (and failing) to get its proxy settings from the ones defined for the system.

Add `--proxy-server="socks5://1.2.3.4:8080` to chrome's command line (for instance by editing the [properties of a shortcut](http://www.misctechmusings.com/browsers/google-chrome-socks5-command-line-switch/)).
Of course, change the `1.2.3.4:8080` to whatever SOCKS5 proxy address and port you should use.