# Delphi/C#: WebBrowser socks5 proxy (with username/password auth)

Tags: c#, delphi, webbrowser-control, socks, twebbrowser

How to use SOCKS 5 proxy with login/password in WebBrowser (IE 8/9)?

In Delphi I tried something like this:

```
var
  PIInfo: PInternetProxyInfo;
begin
  New(PIInfo);
  PIInfo^.dwAccessType := INTERNET_OPEN_TYPE_PROXY;
  PIInfo^.lpszProxy := PChar('socks=127.0.0.1:1080');
  PIInfo^.lpszProxyBypass := PChar('');
  UrlMkSetSessionOption(INTERNET_OPTION_PROXY, piinfo, SizeOf(Internet_Proxy_Info), 0);
  Dispose(PIInfo);
  WebBrowser1.Navigate('http://www.google.com');
end;
```

but looks like it works only if proxy doesn't require login/password authentication.

Comment: As well as Delphi. Maybe someone who use C# know solution for this problem. For me both languages are suitable.

Answer (score 0):

[Bsalsa's embedded webbrowser](http://bsalsa.com/downloads.html) allows you to specify proxy username/password.

Comment: As I know it supports only HTTP proxy, not SOCKS 5.

Comment: I am not certain if IE8/9 supports socks5: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8324536/800214 ?? http://superuser.com/a/383612

Comment: I would say: try it with TEmbeddedWb (use socks5:// prefix for your proxyserver)